# Packaging my Qt-Binary Application as a Snap

Tags: snap

I do not mean any offense, but the Snappy/Snapcraft documentation leaves something to be desired. In particular I am kind of lost of what I have to do to handle this supposedly simple use-case:

My application consists of a bunch of compiled binary files including all necessary libs (in my case Qt 5.7) and a bunch of ressource files. I need to ship these as custom libs, I don't want snapcraft to compile or build anything. Really just copy the libs and ensure that my shipped libs are used instead of any system defaults.

Is there any example for this? In the snappy-playpen repo, it seems there are only more complex cases where something is downloaded from somewhere else, or something put together from existing packages etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `dump` plugin for this case: http://snapcraft.io/docs/reference/plugins/dump

It should be put it all into one directory and you can use `filesets` to specify which bits exactly you want copied over. Use `organize` for renaming things.

Find more examples [here](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=filename%3Asnapcraft.yaml+%22plugin%3A+dump%22+&s=indexed&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: The github link appears to be broken, and I'm not sure exactly how to fix it. (I tried a few variations, but none yielded useful results.)

Comment: The github link works for me. For example https://github.com/kubiko/wekan-snap/blob/master/snapcraft.yaml is on the list and seems to do what you need. It even uses the `dump` plugin for two parts. The last part `helpers` is probably what you need.